# Bootstrap - Align text and icons on sidebar

Tags: html, css

As we can see in the sidebar the icons are aligned left, but the text not.

So the question is: How can i align the icons and the text?

[image: sidebar]

Example code is

```
      <li [routerLinkActive]=" ['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
        <a [routerLink]="['/notificaciones/listado']">
          <i class="fa fa-bell"></i> {{'notifications' | translate}}
        </a>
      </li>
      <li [routerLinkActive]=" ['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
        <a [routerLink]="['/analitica-avanzada/grafica']">
          <i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> {{'advance-analytics' | translate}}
        </a>
      </li>
```

Comment: Please set the minimum width for "i" tag in css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using FontAwesome in your example.

FontAwesome 5+ itself shows the solution:

Just use "**fa-fw**" in the icons-class.

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons

```
<div><i class="fas fa-skating fa-fw" style="background:DodgerBlue"></i> Skating</div>
<div><i class="fas fa-skiing fa-fw" style="background:SkyBlue"></i> Skiing</div>
<div><i class="fas fa-skiing-nordic fa-fw" style="background:DodgerBlue"></i> Nordic Skiing</div>
<div><i class="fas fa-snowboarding fa-fw" style="background:SkyBlue"></i> Snowboarding</div>
<div><i class="fas fa-snowplow fa-fw" style="background:DodgerBlue"></i> Snowplow</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have the same width for all the icons, so in your css you can do something like:

```
i{
  width: 12px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

Please change the values according your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is wrap the `fontawesome` `<i>` tag using another `<span>` tag, and apply a `min-width` value.

***HTML***

```
<li [routerLinkActive]=" ['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
   <a [routerLink]="['/notificaciones/listado']">
     <span class="fa-icon">
       <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
     </span>
     {{'notifications' | translate}}
   </a>
 </li>
```

***CSS***

```
.fa-icon {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width: 20px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```